# Django urls and Angular ui-routes

Tags: angularjs, django, angular-ui-router

I am front developer for django and angular app. For each templateUrl should I need to defined that in django urls. Else I am getting 404 not found for the templateUrl.  Is there a way to directly fetch the files from server, other defining django url and serving the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just put your template in the static directory. When ui-router will fetch your template, it will be like any other static files for django.